# Adding URLs to firefox visited history links

Tags: firefox, history, sqlite, places.sqlite

Is there any way to add links to firefox history like bookmarks?
I want Firefox remember those as visited links without opening them

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that as of the time I post this, latest update is from 2014 and there are major changes coming to add-on APIs from Mozilla. So this add-on is very likely to be outdated & not working or at the very least in need of serious updates.

I have also not tested it, so it may already not work on some versions of Firefox.

---

You can use [Link Visitor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/link-visitor-5/) for manual marking.

It allows for marking URLs as visited or not, manipulating history directly.

Thankfully one of features is operations on selection, so you can mark multiple links at once (use Ctrl+drag to make multiple disjointed selections).

---

*I'm also somewhat curious about sqlite solution to this as well.*

Comment: [The SQLite solution](https://superuser.com/a/1290338/45163)