# Remove suggestion from Firefox autocomplete in URL input field

Tags: firefox, autocomplete

I'm absolutely staggered to have such a hard time finding an answer to this. Now, to make this clear, I am **not** talking about any of the entries in the dropdown that pops up once you type something into the url bar, so please do not suggest using the arrow keys and pressing `shift` + `delete`, that's not what I'm looking for but seems to be the common answer everywhere. I am talking about the blue backgrounded text that automatically fills inside of the url input field itself.

So, when I type `di` the input field automatically completes my input with `ct.leo.org` with a blue background. If I press enter then, I get sent to `dict.leo.org`, logically. This is not where I want to go though, but instead I would like Firefox to automatically fill in `ct.cc`, so I want to keep being able to just type in `di` + `enter` to get sent to the correct page. I merely want that page to be a different one than Firefox suggests.

Now, wondering as to why Firefox is so reluctantly suggesting this specific site, I assume it's because in the past I've used it extensively until they've recently changed their cookies policy, so I decided to switch. Is it possible I have to delete all entries of that page in my history? I would assume there should be a simple to find setting where you could black-/whitelist pages for suggestion or ideally prioritize but I can't find any; only for the dropdown-list I've never cared about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I assume it's because in the past I've used it extensively

Correct. To stop this behaviour:

1. Open `about:preferences`
2. Search for `Browsing history`
3. Uncheck (When using the address bar, suggest) `Browsing history`

> [image]

Comment: Is that the only way? This would remove all history suggestions, but I'd like to remove only this one.

Comment: This old one [Add or edit entry in Firefox history - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1290337/add-or-edit-entry-in-firefox-history) might still work.

Comment: I've eventually ended up searching for the site in my history and then deleted all entries. That worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- Open that site again
- Open the Library window to see your full history (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Right-click on a history entry for that site and use the `Forget about this site` option
- Remove all bookmarks that point to that site, if any

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This also removes passwords, cookies, cache, etc. Wouldn't matter in this case but generally not exactly what I was looking for. Thanks anyways.